# Getting wrong prediction for cnn (Dogs Vs Cat ) Keras

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, convolution

I have programmed convolutional neural network in keras to predict whether the image is of a cat or a dog.
I got an accuracy around 80%.
I tried checking the prediction of my code for many images as it always gave result of the one class out of the classes (dogs and cat) to be predicted.

I will walk you through my code:

The first part of my code is Data Preparation:

```python
#Labels
Y = np.concatenate([np.array([[1,0]]*len(cats)), 
                    np.array([[0,1]]*len(dogs))])
print(Y)

#Features
import scipy.misc
from keras.models import model_from_json
X=[]
for name in cats:
    converted_image =  scipy.misc.imresize(scipy.misc.imread(name), (64, 64))                   
    X.append(converted_image)
for name in dogs:
    converted_image = scipy.misc.imresize(scipy.misc.imread(name), (64, 64))
    X.append(converted_image)


X= np.array(X)
print(len(X))
print(X.shape)
```

Now I have divided the data into training and testing

```python
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.10,random_state=10)
X_train=X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")
print("Shape Of the Training Features are :",X_train.shape)
print("Shape Of Testing Features are  :",X_test.shape)
print("Number of Training Samples : ",X_train.shape[0])
print("Number of Testing Samples :",X_test.shape[0])
```

Now, I will show my complete CNN architecture below:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Lambda,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D

def layer(input_shape = (64,64,3)):
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5 - 1.,input_shape=input_shape, output_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv1', input_shape=input_shape, padding="valid"))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',name='conv2',padding='valid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',name='conv3',padding='valid'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    #model.add(Dense(25088,activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense(12000,activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense(6000,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    return model
model = layer()
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

My accuracy and score from the output is as follows:
Test score: 0.1459069953918457
Test accuracy: 0.7876

-Saving and loading The Model Code

```python
#saving
model_json = model.to_json()
open('cd.json','w').write(model_json)
#Save Weights
model.save_weights('cd_weights.h5',overwrite=True)

#loading
model_architecture = 'cd.json'
model_weights = 'cd_weights.h5'
model = model_from_json(open(model_architecture).read())
model.load_weights(model_weights)
```

Now prediction part

```python
img_names = ['d1.jpg','c1.jpg']
imgs = [np.transpose(scipy.misc.imresize(scipy.misc.imread(img_name), (64, 64)),
                     (1, 0, 2)).astype('float32')
           for img_name in img_names]
imgs = np.array(imgs) / 255

# train
optim = SGD()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim,
    metrics=['accuracy'])

predictions = model.predict_classes(imgs)
print(predictions)
```

Output : [0 0]
The images are taken from training set c1-cat, d1-dog for every image it outputs zero as predicted.

Comment: whats the output of model.predict(imgs)?

Comment: predictions = model.predict(imgs)                                                                    print(np.argmax(predictions ))

Comment: try the above one

Comment: The output is 0 @ShashiTunga

Comment: for this model.predict(imgs)?

Comment: Output for model,predict(imgs): [[0.7865448  0.21910465]
 [0.7856076  0.22000787]] @ShashiTunga

Comment: Don't divide the input by 255 during predictions, as you haven't done this during train.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with model.predict_classes() function.
You can use the following code to perform the same thing as model.predict_classes() can do.

This will give us the prediction in terms of probability.

```
predictions = model.predict(imgs)
```

ex:
1) [0.7865448 0.21910465] says there is 78% chance of the picture being the first class (cat) and 21% of chance being the second class(dog)
2)  [0.7856076 0.22000787] says there is 78% chance of the picture being the first class (cat) and 21% of chance being the second class(dog)

In order to convert this probability to classes  we use np.argmax function.

```
print(np.argmax(predictions ))
```

Your output will be 0 indication first class(cat)
                 or 1 indication second class(dog)

Comment: I want to know where my mistake is

Comment: Try giving more input images to predict,lets see if we would get all zeros .

Comment: I think the problem is we giving just 2 images and taking an eary conclution that the prediction is wrong. Probably predicting on 100 images will let us know if there is a problem or not

Comment: I tried on 20 images every time it gave 0 same class

Comment: Just to confirm,all those 20 images are not cat right.?

Comment: Nope,All mixed  Distribution is some what same for all values in predict